# EmberJS jQuery deprecation and Foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, zurb-foundation, ember-cli

I have an ember project, built using `ember-cli`, where I use `foundation-sites`. To initalize foundation, I do

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';

export default function initFoundation() {
    jQuery(document).foundation();
}
```

I have `@ember/jquery` as a dependency, and the code works as expected. However, I get thousands, or even millions of warnings, telling me

> Using Ember.$() has been deprecated, use `import jQuery from 'jquery';` instead

When I look at the built code, it actually looks like

```
exports.default = initFoundation;
    function initFoundation() {
        Ember.$(document).foundation();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way of fixing this warning? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in Ember 3.9. Upgrade to 3.9 or later to fix it.

Source: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/17908

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer! The newest version of `ember-cli` is `3.18` --what is it that should be updated to `3.9`?

Comment: If this answer is correct, you will want to upgrade your app itself to 3.9. Instructions are here: https://cli.emberjs.com/release/basic-use/upgrading/#upgradinganemberappitself

Comment: Hi @handlebears that works, indeed! However, I also noticed that just updating `ember-cli-babel` from version 6 to version 7 did fix the problem for me. Should I write that as an answer, or rather tag this very answer as a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Updating Ember *e.g. using `ember-cli-update`), as suggested by @NicholasJohn16, fixes the problem.

A more lightweight solution, that fixed the problem for me, was updating just the package `ember-cli-babel`:

```
npm install ember-cli-babel@latest
```

I updated from version 6.x.x to version 7.x.x and the deprecation warning was gone